# getting atlas.launch to run

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

cannot get atlas.launch to work.
I installed 12.04 ubuntu 64 bit. installed ROS and gazebo as per the wiki page.  When I ran the drc simulator atlas.launch.

I get the following.  nny ideas..

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.4.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.0.0.10
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error [RenderEngine.cc:623] Unable to create glx visual
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:87] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.0.0.10
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error [RenderEngine.cc:623] Unable to create glx visual
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:87] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
Warning [InsertModelWidget.cc:242] The manifest.xml for a Gazebo model is deprecated. Please rename manifest.xml to model.config for model "/usr/share/drcsim-2.1/gazebo_models/environments/stepping_block"
gazebo: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::rendering::UserCamera]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1710/getting-atlas.launch-to-run/) by [dezulm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/249/dezulm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks!  I have a lenovo thinkpad w520 which comes with nvidia quadro card but I did not install any additional drivers. It is currently using the default ubuntu drivers.  I did not see nvidia drivers for quadro board on the list of nvidia drivers anyway.

---

Originally posted by [dezulm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/249/dezulm/) with karma: 16 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-03-11**:
check if your GPU is properly installed, here is a way: install mesa utils $ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils and then run $ glxgears